# How to make an UEFI bootable ISO without any partition

Tags: iso

I am trying to repack a bootable UEFI ISO for *arm64* but have no luck.

The ISO looks like

```
# fdisk -l server1030_3.iso
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

So unlike other bootable ISO typically being partitioned into several partitions,
the one that does not have any partition.

I try to use `grub-mkrescue` or `xorriso` but seems they create new partitions and not including
filesystem content as I expect.

So my question is how to repack this ISO and still keep it bootable.

Comment: You just format the entire storage device with FAT32 (exFAT might also work, when supported by the UEFI, but FAT32 is the more safer choice). Then you just copy all files to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any tool to automate what you are asking. However, you can partition a drive largen then your iso, create a partition, write the iso to the partition, and read the disk to another iso file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).